# Trigger click on div so it will scroll on pagedown and pageup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When I physically use the mouse to click on my div, then pageUp and pageDown scroll the div.  However, when I programmatically trigger a click on the div, then pageUp and pageDown fail to scroll the div.  How can I get pageUp and pageDown to scroll the div without the user having to physically click in the div?

**Details:**

What I am trying to do is to let the user pageDown to the bottom of the div, then one more pageDown loads the next set of content into the div and auto-scrolls to the top; and vice versa for pageUp.  It works great as long as the user has clicked inside the div.  I am trying to make it so they don't have to actually click in the div to be able to scroll via pageDown or pageUp.

I am certain that the programmatic click is happening because the click event listeners get triggered.  My pageUp listener also works to load the previous set of content (because the scroll bar starts out at the top).

I am developing within Node-Webkit (Chrome) and angular.js, but cross-browser support is also necessary.

Things I have tried:

```
$('#div').click();
$('#div')[0].click();
$('#div').trigger('click');
$('#div').focus();
$('.focusableThingInsideDiv').focus();
$('#div').scroll();  //just trying random things at this point
```

I have also tried stopping the default browser behavior and implementing the scroll myself (via setting scrollTop).  This technically works.  However, I would prefer not to override the default behavior if possible.

Comment: Maybe I'm having a problem visualizing the actual thing, but is not there a reason that your pageUP/DOWN events need to be local to the div!? Why not put those my press events on the page as a whole?

Comment: @oobivat The events *are* on the page as a whole.  My special event part works.  It's the built-in browser-driven scrolling thing that doesn't work except when an actual click has occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *page up* and *page down* work, after you click on the `div`, because it gains focus. So, although it does not show as a focused element after clicking,  you still want the `$('#div').focus()` line.

The tricky part is that to be able to focus on a `div` programatically you need to give it a `tabindex`. Something like `<div tabindex="0">...</div>` will make the focus suddenly work in Chrome.

Other browsers (IE and Firefox) do not seem to required this. The `focus()` will work from the start but adding `tabindex=0` will not hurt.

Comment: This works, but I'm not sure your first sentence is correct.  The div was not gaining focus when clicked on (either by the user or programmatically), according to either document.activeObject or the jQuery :focus selector.  That is what threw me off as to exactly what was causing pageDown/pageUp to work.

Comment: I was thinking conceptually. If it does not match `:focus` after clicking on it then you are right and my first sentence is misleading. I'll edit to include your observation.